# How to get the time of previous set Alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am developing an app in which i want to show the previous set Alarm on the view. From this code we can check that Alarm is active or not. But how can we get the time

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
    new Intent("com.in.pack.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION"), 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

if (alarmUp)
{
    Log.d("Tag", "Alarm is active");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your alarms in a database.